# cognito lambda (RDS sync) trigger (PostConfirmation) timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, timeout, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-triggers

i was working in a simple function to keep sync my RDS user table and Cognito

```
export async function main (event, context, callback) {

    try {
      let user, User

      User    = models.User

      console.log('before insert',new Date())  
      user = await User.create({
        name:           event.request.userAttributes.name,
        lastName:       event.request.userAttributes.family_name,
        email:          event.request.userAttributes.email,
        organizationId: event.request.userAttributes['custom:organizationId'],
        roleId:         event.request.userAttributes['custom:roleId']
      })

      console.log('after insert', new Date())
      callback(null, event)
      console.log('after callback',new Date())

    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
      callback(e, event)
    }
}
```

[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSbRU.png)

According to the logs as you can see this function respect the 5 seconds of execution, so why never ended? and why cognito make  3 attempts?

Answer (score 1):

so finally i found that [context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html) (-- default true) must be set it to false for those cases where you want the Lambda function to return immediately after you call the callback, regardless of what's happening in the event loop, as i have my db connection object in a global variable, so thats is the reason of this behavior